# How to set a state from a page after redirect from signIn Callback in next-auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, oauth-2.0, next-auth

I'm trying to implement an option to link different providers in the account settings while the user is logged in. I want to show an error message or a modal if the provider account, such as Gmail, is already linked to someone else.

Account Setting Page

```
const [isError, setError] = useState(false);

function handleLinkGoogle() {
  // Sign in function from next-auth
  signIn("google");
}

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={handleLinkGoogle}>Link Google Account</button>
    {isError && <h1>That account's already in use</h1>}

  </>
);
```

Auth Options

```
const handler = NextAuth({
providers: [
GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ]
callbacks: {
  async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {

    // Check if the user is currently signed-in. Otherwise, its for signing-in and not linking
    if(isSignedIn) {

    // Check if the account is already linked to an existing user
    if (accountIsLinked) {
      // set error state from the Account Settings page to true
    }
    }

    // Otherwise, return true to allow the linking / Signing-in
    return true;
  },
}
})
```

The first thing that came to my mind is to redirect in the signIn callback and add a query parameter like this:

```
 if (accountIsLinked) {
      return "/accountSetting?failed=true";
    }
```

...and check if that query parameter is set in the Account Setting Page.

```
const failed = searchParams.get("failed");
if(failed) setError(true);
```

The problem with this approach is when the user manually adds this query parameter to the URL, they will see the error message or modal even though they're not supposed to.

Any workarounds or alternative approach?

Comment: Your work around is good. you can remove the param from the link once the popup is shown. but you can also set the failed flag in the localStorage and on account page, you can check that if it is set show the popup and remove the item.